# object destructuring in enhanced object literals

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Is there any way in ES6 to do the following in one line or a bit shorter?

```
const { bar } = this.foo;
this.module.func({
  bar,
});
```

What I tried is the following which doesn't work and is a syntax error.

```
const { bar } = this.foo;
this.module.func({
  { bar }: this.foo, // unexpected token
});
```

Comment: `this.module.func({
  bar: this.foo.bar
});`

Comment: @adiga the point is not to repeat the `bar` twice.

Comment: Just because ES6 has destructing doesn't make ES5 code legacy. This is simple and cleaner than using additional `{}` and make the code harder to read

Comment: @adiga makes sense, thank you.

Comment: For the record, the actual ECMAScript term is `destructuring`. ( "Destruction" in English would be more like "deleting" the object.)

Comment: @Cat thanks, never had noticed but make perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it as a one-liner unless you repeat the property name:

```
this.module.func({ 
    bar: this.foo.bar
});
```